# compatibility devices for google play services

Tags: google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

i wanna test my game that uses google play services api(for realtime multiplayer). But i don´t have an android phone or tablet, i only use the emulator.
Is there a specific model of phone that i should buy to use google play services or will it work on any android device?

On emulators, there´s a "target name" called google APIS, so i was wondering about the device.

I have already made my game work on emulators, but even of ButtonClicker example, there´s a delay on the timer on one of the emulators and not on the other. Maybe i should try with a real device?

Answer (score 0):

It will work on any Android phone (not Android compatible).  Avoid devices like the Kindle Fire that are compatible, but not actually Android.  If it has the Google Play app and it's running Ice Cream Sandwich or higher, you should be set.

The Nexus devices tend to be developer favorites, as they have no customization from carriers or manufacturers and are fairly cheap.  Developer Editions would be a good alternative.